# Не генерируются события во Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, события

Есть js-файл, который собирается с помощью **Laravel Mix**. В нём ранее было 2 компонента, после чего появилась потребность в регистрации нового. После того, как прописал всю необходимую логику, решил запустить. Собрал bundle. Проверяю. Не реагирует на нажатие. В коде всё правильно. При сборке ошибок не было. В консоли разработчика тоже пусто. Решил просто вкинуть **console.log**. Мало ли. Ничего не помогло. В результате, сделал копию *текущего_исходника.vue*, а в оригинале всё стёр и написал просто

```
<template>
<v-btn @click="console.log('adfesfwf')">ajvarhe</v-btn>
</template>
```

Да-да, у меня подключен Vuetify. Кнопки корректно отображаются, но в консоли, по нажатию, пусто. При этом, я использую DevTools для Vue, где очень удобно можно просматривать отправляемые события. За всё время отладки данной ошибки, не было зафиксировано ни одного события. При этом, хуки работают (проверял только **created**). Пробовал создать совершенно другой компонент. Ровно та же проблема.
Хочу обратить внимание на то, что предыдущие 2 компонента вполне корректно работают. Сколько не было пересборок, события работают.

Comment: должна быть ошибка в стиле "Cannot read property 'log' of undefined"
вызывайте метод по клику, и пробуйте использовать модификатор [.native](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%85)

Comment: Дело в том, что эта ошибка не выскакивает. А вот когда я попытался это всё загрузить на CodePen, она стала выскакивать. При этом, полностью загрузить не удалось из-за большого размера bundle. Native уже пробовал. Мне кажется, я пробовал уже всё, что только можно. Я не первый день пишу на этом. Столько компонентов написал. Те же самые 2 предыдущих компонента в этом же файле, которые нормально работают. А тут какая-то вообще не понятная проблема. На ровном месте не работает.

Comment: Я задал этот же вопрос на англоязычной версии сайта:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60496687/no-events-are-generated-in-vue
Возможно, поможет как-то то обсуждение в комментариях, @ryzen

Answer (score 1):

Срабатывание события на компоненте, будет только в том случае, если компонент генирирует это событие `$emit('click')`. Другими словами, в Вашем случае, `<v-btn @click="console.log('adfesfwf')"></v-btn>` равносильно `<v-btn @bla-bla-bla="console.log('adfesfwf')"></v-btn>`. Если же Вы желаете подписаться на нативное событие, на компоненте, то необходимо воспользоваться спефицальным модификатором `native`. В Вашем  случае, выглядить это будет так `<v-btn @click.native="console.log('adfesfwf')">ajvarhe</v-btn>`